# Unable to clear canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am having a really difficult time resetting / clearning the contents of my canvas. I am currently using the : [Sketch.js](http://intridea.github.com/sketch.js/) plugin to generate a free form canvas. It does exactly what I need it to, however, it does not seem to have an simple canvas 'reset' function call to clear the contents.

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/k7fmq/

**NOTE:** I read that the 'width' method does not work in chrome, and both methods don't seem to work on a 'free-form' canvas, but only on shapes, which I did not test.

This is what I tried so far:

Markup

```
<div class="signature-field">
            Signature:
    <span class="sketch-container">
            <canvas style="border:1px solid grey; border-radius:7px;" id="simple_sketch" width="400" height="150"></canvas>
            <span class="save-signature">Save Signature</span>
            <span class="reset-canvas">Reset Canvas</span>
    </span>
    Date: <input type="text"><br/><br/>Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text">
</div>
```

JQuery (My latest attempt)

```
$('.reset-canvas').click(function() {
        var myCanvas = document.getElementById("#simple_sketch");
        var width = myCanvas.width;
        myCanvas.width = width + 1;

 });
```

Method 2:

```
  $('.reset-canvas').click(function() {
           canvas.width = canvas.width; 
   });
```

Method 3:

```
$('.reset-canvas').click(function() {
       var myCanvas = document.getElementById("simple_sketch");
       var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
       ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
 });
```

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701380/clearrect-does-not-clear-the-canvas-when-drawing-vertical-lines

Comment: Where's the code that draws this image?

Comment: It is drawn by the user using a free-form brush, it will be different every time. The code that actually handles this free-form brush capability is here:  http://intridea.github.com/sketch.js/lib/sketch.js

Comment: Can you set up a working fiddle demonstrating your problem?

Comment: What are the values of x, y, w, h and context in method 3? `context.clearRect (0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)` should work, as long as the appropriate `context` and `canvas` are within the function's scope.

Comment: @Stuart, Please see edited method 3.

Comment: @Shmiddty, here is jsfiddle demonstration of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/k7fmq/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/k7fmq/1/

The sketchpad plugin keeps an array of "actions", and redraws them each update (which seems unnecessary, really, but whatevs).

```
var sktch = $('#simple_sketch').sketch();  // store a reference to the element.
var cleanCanvas = $('#simple_sketch')[0];

$('.save-signature').click(function(){
    /* replace canvas with image */
    var canvas = document.getElementById("simple_sketch");
    var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    $('#simple_sketch').replaceWith('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
    $('.signature-buttons').replaceWith('');
});
$('.reset-canvas').click(function(){
    sktch.sketch().actions = [];       // this line empties the actions. 
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("simple_sketch");
    var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
});
```

Comment: +1; just one note: the "actions" array is a perfectly valid design choice; it makes it a lot easier to implement undo functionality, for example.

Comment: @Shmiddy, perfect! thank you very much, have been trying to figure this one out for a while! :)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.save();
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This method did not work for me. It clears canvas, but when I try to reuse the canvas after the reset, the previous image that was 'cleared' appears again.