# clearRect does not clear the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to draw rectangle in canvas, users click on spot and moves the mouse, the rectangle will be drawn and when its done only one rectangle remanins, the alst one. However using

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"), ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",function(event){
    x_ = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    y_ = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;  
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(event){
        xmax = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        ymax = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        console.log(x_,y_,xmax,ymax);
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
        ctx.rect(x_,y_,xmax-x_,ymax-y_);
        ctx.stroke()
    })
})
```

```css
canvas {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kb9euqnp/3/)

The `clearRect` call does not work, as the previous rectangles remain visible.

There is no reason for it not to work, why does it behaves in such way? After clearing the rectangle, the new image is drawn, and all previous rectangles should go away.

Comment: I see you're calling `stroke()` at the end. Check the "Usage notes" section here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clearRect does not clear the canvas when drawing vertical lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701380/clearrect-does-not-clear-the-canvas-when-drawing-vertical-lines)

Answer (score 3):

I see you're calling `stroke()` at the end, that might be the problem. Check the "Usage Notes" here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect

> A common problem with clearRect is that it may appear it does not work when not using paths properly. **Don't forget to call beginPath() before starting to draw the new frame after calling clearRect.**

Answer (score 1):

Try: Using `beginPath()` after calling `clearRect()`.

```
    [...]
    console.log(x_,y_,xmax,ymax);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
    [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an object to maintain state. Your code is just stacking event listeners and creating a singular shape. We use `context.beginPath()` to advise of a new shape.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"), ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
mouse = { 
mousedown: false,
x: 0,
y: 0
}
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",function(event){
    mouse.x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouse.y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;  
    mouse.mousedown = true;
})
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup mouseleave",function(event){

    mouse.mousedown = false;
})
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(event){
        xmax = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        ymax = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
        
        if(mouse.mousedown) {
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 10);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(mouse.x, mouse.y, xmax-mouse.x,ymax-mouse.y);
        ctx.stroke()
        }
    })
```

```css
canvas {
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```